# How to pass a local string to a partial in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**TL;DR Version of Question**

Is it possible to pass a string to a partial and have the partial use that string in an if statement or switch case.

Am I breaking some valuable rule of Rails by having the views talk directly to each other?

**Long Version w/ Code Snippets**

I think it's safe to say that at this point in time I've read every post there is about how to pass a local variable. I'm still having trouble with accomplishing this. I'm very new to rails, like.. 1 week of learning, so what I'm trying to do might be completely incorrect.

Anyways, I have it set up so that when a user clicks a link on the navbar a bootstrap modal loads with the correct form inside of it. I've set each unique form as their own partial so that I can just drop there in where needed and I've also setup the modal as a partial. I'm trying to follow this DRY method and make it so that in the modal partial it has a if/else or switch logic that only loads the correct form based on what the link passes it.

Modal Partial:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalTemplate" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal Template</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <% if %VARIABLE% == "%PASSED-INPUT%" %>
          <% @customer = Customer.new %>
          <%= render "customers/new" %>
        <% elsif %VARIABLE% == "%PASSED-INPUT%" %>
          --> Do something else
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

NavBar Partial:

```
<%= render 'layouts/modal_template' %>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-side">
    <h6 class="navbar-heading">Customer Management</h6>
  <div class="list-group">
    <%= link_to "Add New Customer", '#modalTemplate', 'data-toggle' => 'modal', what_to_render: "Test", class: 'list-group-item' %>
    <%= link_to "Manage Customers", '#', class: 'list-group-item' %>
    </div>
    <h6 class="navbar-section-heading">Customer Status Management</h6>
    <div class="list-group">
    <%= link_to "Add New Customer Status", new_customers_status_path, class: 'list-group-item' %>
    <%= link_to "Manage Customer Statuses", '#', class: 'list-group-item' %>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The Main View for this Page:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2">
      <%= render 'layouts/side-nav' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-10">
      <div class="well">
        <%= render 'test' %>
        <%= render 'view_customers' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, the "Added New Customer" link_to is the part that is giving me the most trouble. I've tried every different combination provided online, but it always seems to be based around the idea of working with an object or something from the database. Thing is, I'm just trying to load a different page based on the selected button all while using the same modal partial.

link_to Examples that I've Tried:

```
<%= link_to "Add New Customer", '#modalTemplate', 'data-toggle' => 'modal', what_to_render: "Test", class: 'list-group-item' %>
<%= link_to "Add New Customer", '#modalTemplate', 'data-toggle' => 'modal', :locals => { what_to_render: "Test" }, class: 'list-group-item' %>
```

There are more, but I've deleted so many lines of code at this point that I've lost them. Some included using the link_to with :partial and :locals

Comment: `:locals` is an option for `render`, not `link_to`.

Comment: pass locals while you rendering partial not in link_to helper.

Comment: The `ruby-on-rails-x`  tags are to indicate that the question is for a specific version of rails. Don't use more than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing together a few quite different concepts and you should probaly get the basics straight before attempting this task.

To pass a variable between requests you would use params. This can be be in the form of URL segment, the query string or the request body (by using a form). Since a variable on the server does not persist between requests you can't pass local variables to `link_to` and I have no idea where you got the notion that it would work.

- https://www.codecademy.com/articles/request-response-cycle-dynamic
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

`locals` on the other hand is a way to assign a local variable in the rendering context of a partial. You can use this to pass any type of data.

```
# foo/index.html.erb
<%= render :bar, locals: { a: 1 } %>

# foo/_bar.html.erb
<% if a == 1 %>

<% elsef a ==  2 %>

<% end %>
```

But to get back to your question. There are a few different ways to solve it.

The first is to include all the forms on the page and then swap the content of the modal based on what user clicks. You can do this by using plain old html anchor links instead of `link_to` and creating a javascript listener which intercepts the click event and instead opens the link target in a modal.

The second is to use an ajax request to fetch the rendered version of a partial. You would then open a partial with the content fetched from the ajax request.

This can be solved in a number of ways by for example using `jQuery.load` or the rails ujs components and creating a `.js.erb` template.

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: At your skill level I would skip the modal and just implement it in as just plain old links that renders another page with the form. Later you can add the modal as a form of progressive enhancement.

Comment: Thanks for the links and the info, I'll probably follow what you said and just get it working before I try and make it fancy.

Answer (score 0):

As some people comented, the "partial" option is for the render method, not the link_to.

Something like this would probably work for you:

```
<a href="#modalTemplate" data-toggle="modal" class="list-group-item">Add New Customer</a>
<%= render "your/modal/partial/path" %>
```

**Unrelated Tip:**

Avoid at all costs setting instance variables in the view. In this case you should probably had set it at the controller :)